# HTML Form/PHP connected but MySQL is empty

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I'm setting up a contact form for my domain I have succeeded in created the database and tables from the cPanel but I'm having trouble getting the PHP code to work. I was able to establish a connection between the HTML form and the Database using PHP. When I hit "SUBMIT" on the form, it connects to the database and I get a 'success' message.

However, when I log in and check the MySQL Database through PHPmyadmin I can see that it indeed created a new row in the table, but it is blank.

I have spent hours combing the syntax line by line and can't seem to find anything out of place and I have now added a bunch of troubleshooting steps in to try and solve it.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

The HTML form is as follows:

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post" name="sentMessage" id="contactForm">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
<div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name *" name="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email *" name="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Phone *" name="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6">

        <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Your Message *" name="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
        <div id="success"></div>
        <button type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-xl">Send Message</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

And the PHP file connecting the HTML form to MySQL is:

```
<?PHP
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', myUserName', 'myPassword', 'myDatabase');


if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}


$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['name'], $link);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['email'], $link);
$phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['phone'], $link);
$message = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['message'], $link);


$sql = "INSERT INTO 1stChoice_Contact (name, email, phone, message) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$phone', '$message')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Your message has been sent!";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

if(empty($_POST['name'])      ||
   empty($_POST['email'])     ||
   empty($_POST['phone'])     ||
   empty($_POST['message'])   ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
   echo "No arguments Provided!";
   return false;
   }

$name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
$email_address = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
$phone = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']));
$message = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']));


$to = 'sample@yourgmail.com'; 
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$headers = "From: youremail@yourdomain.com\n"; 
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";   
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;         

 header('location:index.html');

?>
```

Comment: your code is failing on a few levels

Comment: You have not selected a database while connecting

Comment: Give the missing opening tag of form with method post

Comment: I had the Form tag all along. Just missed it while I was copying the code to paste here.

Comment: Also, I have selected DB, I just deleted the code while posting here for security reasons. What I have is as follows:$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', myUserName', 'myPassword', 'myDatabase');

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing your opening form tag.

also mysqli_real_escape_string first param is the connection, second param is the string and you are not selecting a database.

I suggest having a read up on

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_connect.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_real_escape_string.asp

Comment: I had the Form opening tag, I missed copying it while I was pasting the code on here. My apologies. Also, I tried switching the parameters but I still have the same issue. Communication with the DB is there but because I can see the auto increment ID I assigned to the table increase. However, no strings (data) are added to my table.

Comment: echo out the query eg. echo $sql; and see if it is adding the values correctly to the query or print_r($_POST); to see if your values are being submitted correctly. Also check your column types, make sure the strings have a column type of varchar.